# NextJS Deploy ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, webpack, next.js

im trying to deploy my app to Vercel but having this 
 `ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found : Error: Can't resolve '../../../util/mongodb' in 'C:\WEB-ALL\nextjs_all\koslowshop\pages\api\pages\new'`  error.

its also giving the same error when I type `npm run build` on the vscode terminal. My `package.json` has the mongodb package, I dont really understand what is the problem here...

here is my github repo of this project ; [Github Repo](https://github.com/sbayrak/koslowshop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the relative path, it is wrong, change the code in pages/api/pages/new/index.js to:

```
import { connectToDatabase } from '../../../../util/mongodb';
```